# Mouse.event occurs at any y pos regardless of actual y pos

Tags: python, mouseevent, pygame

The pygame app has two rows of buttons. The buttons can be turned on or off by clicking on them.

The problem is no matter where the mouse is vertically it clicks all the buttons of that column simultaneously, instead of just one; (as if the entire y axis is clicked at once). I printed the x and y coordinates of the mouse event on each click, but the coordinates were within the location of one single button as normal. So why do multiple buttons turn on or off instead of just that one? I even clicked way below any buttons' vertical range and they still were activated as long as the x coordinate was still in range. Here's part of the code anyway (sorry about the poor numbering system):

```
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        if event.pos < (130,130) and event.pos > (100,100):
            if seq01[0] == 0:
                seq01[0] = 1
                block_00 = block_on
            else:
                seq01[0] = 0
                block_00 = block_off
            print event.pos

        if event.pos < (170,130) and event.pos > (140,100):
            if seq01[1] == 0:
                seq01[1] = 1
                block_01 = block_on
            else:
                seq01[1] = 0
                block_01 = block_off

        #### this is the start of the second row ####
        if event.pos < (130,200) and event.pos > (100,170):
            if seq02[0] == 0:
                seq02[0] = 1
                block_2_00 = block_on
            else:
                seq02[0] = 0
                block_2_00 = block_off
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are comparing the mouse position (a pair of integers) with the button corners (another pair of integers). Python compares sequences elementwise, so your test is really only examining the first axis (X).

I would highly recommend creating a pygame.Rect for each button, then you can more simply test if the button is inside that area.

Then your code would look more like this,

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
    if rect_00.collidepoint(event.pos):
        if seq01[0] == 0:
            seq01[0] = 1
            block_00 = block_on
        else:
            seq01[0] = 0
            block_00 = block_off
        print event.pos

    if rect_01.collidepoint(event.pos):
        if seq01[1] == 0:
            seq01[1] = 1
            block_01 = block_on
        else:
            seq01[1] = 0
            block_01 = block_off

    #### this is the start of the second row ####
    if rect_2_00.collidepoint(event.pos):
        if seq02[0] == 0:
            seq02[0] = 1
            block_2_00 = block_on
        else:
            seq02[0] = 0
            block_2_00 = block_off
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparisons are defective.  Consider the following transcript:

```
In [278]: pos=(120, 0)
In [279]: pos > (100,100)
Out[279]: True
In [280]: pos < (130,130)
Out[280]: True
In [281]: pos < (130,200)
Out[281]: True
In [282]: (100,170)
Out[282]: (100, 170)
In [283]: (129,300) < (130,130)
Out[283]: True
In [284]: (130,300) < (130,130)
Out[284]: False
```

Apparently you expected none of those comparisons to be true.  However, in comparing tuples, it is the left-most difference in elements that determines the result.  In your code, the extra comparisons that are satisfied result in extra buttons being activated.